# Одна общая таблица изображений для нескольких сущностей

Tags: mysql, архитектура

Есть 3 таблицы - записи (`items`), страницы (`pages`) и изображения (`images`). В таблице изображений хранятся пути к файлам изображений. Проблема в том, как правильно организовать структуру. Т.е. мне пришлось создать поле `owner_type` и делать выборку по этому условию, т.е. вроде этого

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE owner_id = id AND owner_type = 'item'
```

т.к. id записи и страницы могут совпасть и изображение перезапишется или как минимум выберется не то что нужно. Упрощенно таблица `images` выглядит так

```
images
-------------------------
id | owner_id | owner_type
```

Соответственно в `owner_type` попадает просто строка или 'page' или 'item'. Собственно вопрос, как избавиться от этого `owner_type` ?

Comment: А насколько много общего у items и pages, кроме того, что у каждой могут быть изображения, они не могут быть представлены в виде одной таблицы ?

Comment: Думаю нет, т.к. там очень много полей, и у каждой таблицы(items и pages) их кол-во разное + тип разнный.

Comment: Pages и Items должны ссылаться на Image, а не наоборот.

Comment: Можно поподробнее пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Гость cpp_user предлагает хранить id изображения где то у себя. правда я подозреваю, что у вас к одному объекту может быть несколько изображений. Тогда для pages и items придется делать дополнительные таблицы, каждому свою, по типу page-id:image-id

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Да, связь один ко многим. Еще вычитал, что можно хранить пути к файлам прямо в таблице items, т.е. добавить поле images, и хранить в json массив путей к файлам изображений, правда как-то не по феншую получается. Из плюсов, не нужен доп.запрос к БД.

Answer (score 1):

Если оставлять одну общую таблицу с изображениями, совершенно избавиться от дополнительного столбца `owner_type` не получится. Вам придется как-то идентифицировать принадлежность изображения тому или иному типу.

Однако, можно сократить накладные расходы и размер таблицы изображений. Например, вместо строкового значения `owner_type` можно использовать числовое `owner_type_id`. При желании его можно сделать внешним ключом таблицы `owner_types` (она может не участвовать в запросах, а просто выступать в качестве информационной). Это позволит сократить объем таблицы изображений, что ускорит запросы к ней, кроме того, вместо строки в WHERE-условии будет число, которое обрабатывается быстрее и чей индекс занимает меньше места.

Еще одним способом оптимизации может выступать отсутствие название и пути к файлу. Т.е. храним только идентификатор файла (при загрузке происходит его переименование), а путь к нему вычисляем по идентификатору /path/to/file/23532.jpg. Здесь 23532 - id изображения. Это также уменьшит объем таблицы изображений, а, следовательно, увеличит скорость обработки запросов.